# Property "CheckoutFields" does not have corresponding setter in class "Magento\Quote\Api\Data\AddressExtensionInterface"

Tags: magento2, error, debug

i updated magento, and now in the checkout page i get this error.
How can i debug this?
Thank you!

```
                [2018-07-31 16:16:15] main.CRITICAL: Report ID: webapi-5b608b4fab129; Message: Property "CheckoutFields" does not have corresponding setter in class "Magento\Quote\Api\Data\AddressExtensionInterface". {"exception":"[object] (Exception(code: 0): Report ID: webapi-5b608b4fab129; Message: Property \"CheckoutFields\" does not have corresponding setter in class \"Magento\\Quote\\Api\\Data\\AddressExtensionInterface\". at /home/r2gutenb/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Webapi/ErrorProcessor.php:205, LogicException(code: 0): Property \"CheckoutFields\" does not have corresponding setter in class \"Magento\\Quote\\Api\\Data\\AddressExtensionInterface\". at /home/r2gutenb/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Reflection/NameFinder.php:100)"} []
```

[image]

here the extension_attributes that maybe are causing the problem...